# Capturing packets on VMware machines

Tags: linux

I have a windows PC installed VMware Workstation and Linux run on it. I want When windows communicate with Internet I can capture packets in Linux, how can I do that?

The vmware network is Bridge, and I set eth0 use command "ifconfig eth0 procmisc".

linux IP is 192.168.0.103,   windows IP is 192.168.0.102
Run "tcpdump not host 192.168.0.103" with no result.

Thank you for you time and please help me

Comment: I think this is off-topic here, would be better suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used VMWare workstation before, I have used Oracle VirtualBox in a similar setup as you describe.

I suspect that the problem is that your network adaptor on the Linux VM is not actually accessing the physical network adaptor directly.  You will be using one of the network mapping types described in http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006480 instead.

As such, you are not getting all the traffic that is going to your physical network adaptor.  Instead you are getting the reduced set of traffic that VMWare is passing on to your guest.

The only way to get that is to do the snoop on your Windows host, using something like https://www.wireshark.org/